# request.getparamater

Tags: java

```
int no=request.getParameter(Integer.parseInt("rollnumber"));
```

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The method getParameter(String) in the type ServletRequest is not applicable for the arguments (int)   Controller.java /SecondApp/src  line 21 Java Problem

Answer (score 5):

First of all, please edit your question-title so it is a actual question.

Secondly, you call `parseInt()` in the wrong place.
The correct syntax would be:

```
int no= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rollnumber"));
```

Comment: oh i am sorry my Question was wrong....

Answer (score 1):

```
int no=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rollnumber"));
```